# Illustrator CC Text not turning, acting like indesign text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, creative-cloud

In my CC Illustrator, the text box won't allow me to turn on its side/rotate, every time I try to turn, the text stays horizontal and moves within the box. It is acting like text in indesign. Is there a setting I can change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is because you're actually rotating a text frame...much like InDesign, as you said. You can rotate the object the way you want using the **Rotate Tool (R)** or the **Free Transform Tool (E)**.

Comment: This seems to be a new behaviour in the most recent version of CC. Apparently if you 'free rotate' by dragging the corners of a text box now, it rotates the frame but not the text, and as you've said, you have to use the Rotate tool (R) if you want to rotate the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

This use to happen to me on Photoshop.
Try deleting the layer. Making a new text box and turn off caps lock if you have it on. Then click the word that you are trying to rotate while holding command. Also  make sure you are using the pointer that has the black outline and not the solid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

or u can still rotate it with same method but just u need to add an object withing the tex box

for example text box that u want to rotate and select rectangle obejct with in both together and rotate and it will fix ur problem .

Answer (score 0):

To transform the type along with its bounding path, select the type object and use the Rotate tool to rotate the object and text.

To transform just the bounding path, but not the type it contains, select the type object and drag with the Selection tool.